# how to manipulate android libraries?

Tags: java, android

I have a library that I got it from github and I wanna make changes in some of the methods and layouts.how can I do it?
also I should say my workplace is AndroidStudio and use Gradle for adding library to my project.
Is there a way to manipulate gradle libraries?!

Comment: you can do it if you have full resources of that library, but if you have aar file you cannot change

Comment: Subclass what you need, and if that doesn't work, fork the project.

Comment: You Solved my problem! thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solutions for these:-

- u can download the .zip of the library modify it and import as a module in android studio project
- clone the repository ,modify it and then upload it mavencentral so that u can use as dependency in studio or download .zip after modifying it and import as android studio project

Comment: good point ! thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you use any function related with that library in your project you can access the specific class using Control + Left click on the function and go any deep you need. Then you can make it there the local modificacion of the library.

It is also not so recomended to make major changes.